# Visualforce Controller Test Class - 0% Coverage

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, controller

I have built a Visualforce page that allows the user to quickly choose a file and attach it to the record without having to go to an additional page.  I have been attempting to build a test class for the controller.  I have been able to do successful Tests, but there has been 0% code coverage.  Can anyone please help me understand what I'm missing?

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class AttachmentUploadControllerDemo {

  public String attachmentName {get; set;} 
  public Blob attachmentBody {get; set;}

  public Attachment attachment {
  get {
      if (attachment == null)
        attachment = new Attachment();
      return attachment;
    }
  set;
  }

  public  Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agmt = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c();
  public  Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agmt1 = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c();
  public String redirectUrl {public get; private set;}
  public Boolean shouldRedirect {public get; private set;}
  public Boolean attached {public get; private set;}
  public Boolean notAttached {public get; private set;}
  public Boolean preAttached {public get; private set;}
  public Boolean lpoOwned {public get; private set;}
  public Boolean lpoAttached {public get; private set;}
  ID agmtid;
  String own;

  List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();  
  List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__Share> agreementShares = new List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__Share>();



  String attachedReturn = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('attachedReturn');

  public AttachmentUploadControllerDemo(ApexPages.StandardController Controller) {  
      this.agmt = (Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c)Controller.getRecord();
      shouldRedirect = false;
      agmtid = agmt.id;
      agmt1 = [Select ID, Owner.Name From Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c Where ID=:agmtid LIMIT 1];
      own = agmt1.owner.name;
      if(own=='LPO Storage'){
          preAttached=false;
          lpoOwned = true;
      }
      else{
          preAttached=true;
          lpoOwned = false;
      }

  }

    public PageReference unAttach(){
        notAttached = false;
        preAttached=false;
        lpoAttached=false;
        return null;
    }  

  public PageReference upload() {


    attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    attachment.ParentId = agmt.id; // the record the file is attached to
    attachment.IsPrivate = true;
    attachment.name = attachmentName;
    attachment.body = attachmentBody;
    attachment.isPrivate = false;

    if(attachmentName == null){
        notAttached = true;
        attached = false;
        preAttached=false;
        lpoOwned=false;
        lpoAttached=false;
        return null;
    }
      else{
          try {
            insert attachment;
                if(own=='LPO Storage'){
                  lpoAttached=true;
                  attached=false;
                }
                else{
                  attached = true; 
                  lpoAttached=false;
                }                   
                notAttached = false;
                preAttached=false;
                lpoOwned=false;
            } catch (DMLException e) {
                attached = false;
                notAttached = true;
                preAttached=false;
                lpoOwned=false;
                lpoAttached=false;
                return null;
            } finally {
                attachment = new Attachment(); 
            }
      }


    shouldRedirect = true;
    redirectUrl = '/' + agmt.id;
    return null;
//      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Attachment uploaded successfully'));

}
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
public class AttachmentUploadController_Test {

    private static  testMethod void AttachmentUploadController_Test()
    {

        Profile p = [select id from profile where name='Standard User'];
        User u = new User(alias = 'standt', email='standarduser6@testorg.com',
            emailencodingkey='UTF-8', firstname='fake', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
            localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id,
            timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='standarduser6@testorg.com');
        insert u;

        Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agmt1 = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c();        
        agmt1.Ownerid = u.id;
        insert agmt1;

        Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');

        test.starttest();

        PageReference pgRef = Page.Attach_File_Upload;
        Test.setCurrentPageReference (pgRef);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',agmt1.id);

        AttachmentUploadControllerDemo attch = new AttachmentUploadControllerDemo(new ApexPages.StandardController(agmt1));  
        System.assertEquals(true, attch.preattached);
        attch.unAttach();
        attch.attachmentName = 'Test';
        attch.attachmentBody = bodyBlob;
        attch.upload();
        test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the **"Always Run Asynchronously"** box will fix your test coverage count issue

[image]