# unable to get code coverage for my apex trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test, lead-conversion

Hey i am new to salesforce. I write an apex trigger in lead.Whenever any lead is converted type picklist(standard field) in opportunity object has to updated with new-business.I had successfully wrote trigger for this and it handle bulk records also.My problem is i write a test class for this apex trigger it run successfully but i didn't get any code coverage for my trigger where i had done mistake.

my apex trigger

```
trigger trigMapFields on Lead (before update)  {
public opportunity con;
List<Id> leadStatus= new List<Id>();
      for(Lead lead:System.Trigger.new) 
      {
          if (lead.IsConverted) 
          {
            leadStatus.add(lead.ConvertedOpportunityId);
          }
      } 
List<Opportunity> opps=[select Id from Opportunity WHERE Opportunity.Id IN:leadStatus];
      for(Opportunity o:opps) 
      {
       o.Type='New Business';
      }
     update opps;
}
```

My apex test class

```
@isTest
public class testLeadConvertMapFields { 
static testMethod void trigTest() {

    // Create dummy lead
    Lead testLead = new Lead(Company='Test Lead',FirstName='John',LastName='Doe',Status='Open - Not Contacted');
    insert testLead;

    // Create dummy conversion
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(testLead.id);
    lc.setConvertedStatus('Closed - Converted');
    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);

    // Make sure conversion was successful
    System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

    // Test Opportunity "Status" field update
    Opportunity testCon = [SELECT Type FROM Opportunity WHERE Opportunity.Id = :lcr.getOpportunityId()];
    System.assertEquals(testCon.Type,'New Business');
  }
 }
```

I think i wrote something wrong in test class by checking status field

Comment: run all test and then check coverage. Sometime DC does not display correct code coverage.

Comment: what is your issue.. are you getting any error or just your code coverage is always zero ? or check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104204/visualforce-controller-test-class-0-coverage/104207#104207

Comment: Hey Thanks buddy thanks for sharing knowledge you saved my lot of time bro  @Tushar Sharma..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run all test and then check coverage. Sometime DC does not display correct code coverage.

It will solve your problem.