# Tests passing with 0% coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, eclipse, developer-console, asynchronous-testing

I'm pretty new to apex.
My test classes are passing. But the class is showing zero % coverage
(none of the lines in the actual class were hit (highlighted blue)... which does not make sense.)

Any ideas why this might be happening? 
This just started happening very recently. This happens with both synchronous and asynchronous testing, whether I run one test or multiple tests at a time.

Also some of my classes are not showing up on the test coverage panel on the right hand side of developer console (on the 'tests' tab). 
Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: issue may be this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104204/visualforce-controller-test-class-0-coverage

Comment: @Ratan Not likely since it also happens during async testing...

Comment: Try a run from the Apex Test Execution page in setup instead of from the Developer Console

Comment: If all else fails, try going to Setup>Apex Classes, click on Clear Code Coverage, then Compile all classes. After that do a run all test of your test classes.

Comment: Will try the above and report back... Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Tried all of the above, none seemed to fix the problem. Thanks for the help though! If anyone has ideas for things to try, please let me know.